# Change variable values by groups using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is I want to change all the missing values to the mean of each group for multiple columns. I want to use `dplyr` but it does not work for me

For example

```
iris2 <- iris
set.seed(1)
iris2[-5] <- lapply(iris2[-5], function(x) {
  x[sample(length(x), sample(10, 1))] <- NA
  x
})

impute_missing=function(x){
    x[is.na(x)]=mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)
    return(x)
}

iris2 %>% groupby (Species) %>% sapply(impute_missing)
```

However the codes did not impute the missing by Species but by the mean of all the non-missing values of each column. Another weird thin is the function was also applied to `Species` the group variable. Is there any way to impute the mean by species and keep a complete dataframe/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 library(dplyr)
 iris2New <- iris2 %>% 
                   group_by(Species) %>%
                   mutate_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), contains("."))

 iris2[,-5][is.na(iris2)[,-5]] <- iris2New[,-5][is.na(iris2)[,-5]]

 iris2
```

Or, you could use `ifelse` on the initial dataset `iris2`

```
  fun1 <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), x)
  iris3 <-  iris2 %>% 
                  group_by(Species) %>% 
                  mutate_each(funs(fun1), contains(".") )

  identical(as.data.frame(iris3), iris2)
  #[1] TRUE
```

Or, instead of a `function`, you can use

```
 iris4 <-  iris2 %>% 
                 group_by(Species) %>% 
                 mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), mean(., na.rm=TRUE), .)), contains(".") )


 identical(iris3,iris4)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Comment: awesome!! thanks for your help! but I have a question for the `funs` part we can't include `function(x){}` but use `.` ?

Comment: @MYjx You can use that as a separate function as I showed in `fun1`